# how to delete media files based on file name on Android device

Tags: android, image, video, android-intent

I am trying to create an application that enables the end user to pass file name String which is used to delete the media with corresponding value on the Android device.

I am not sure of how to go about this. Can I use intents?

Much thanks.

Comment: How is the filename chosen? Is that media info stored within the MediaStore?

Comment: Sorry for not giving enough information, the filename is chosen using the Intent.ACTION_VIEW. Now I am wondering how to remove that filename. Hope this is sufficient.

Comment: If you know the path of the fileName then just do a `new File(fileName).delete()`,

Comment: really? Is it that simple? I was thinking you would have to create and call an Intent.

Comment: this is simple java file handling...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to st0le, its really simple actually. Just use:
new File(fileName).delete()